# Skyline Tool: Using angle of elevation from observer point?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, 3d-analyst

Situation:

I want to determine if I can aim an antenna at a satellite from a given location and still receive satellite signals without surface obstacles (e.g., mountains) blocking the antenna. The antenna azimuth would be 146° (magnetic) and the antenna elevation would be 19°.

Question:

I believe the Skyline Tool holds the answer, except that I do not know how to account for the 19° elevation of the antenna within the tool. I've attached a sketch of what I think may hold the answer: taking the sin of the antenna angle and the distance to the nearest mountain, determine the elevation in meters that the antenna must clear and compare this to the height of the peaks. The problem is that foreground foothills and lesser peaks may still obstruct the angle of the antenna, and I want to conduct this exercise on more than one peak, but all surrounding surfaces from 140° to 150° (magnetic).

[image]

This question 1by1 was asked at [geonet.esri](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/120735), but I have got **exactly** same problem.

Answer (score -1):

If the use of ArcMap and this skyline tool is not mandatory, and given that you already have all the necessary numbers bar the height of the peaks, I can imagine it would be fairly straightforward to do with GoogleMaps.

Without getting in too much detail (as the point is moot if the tool is not suitable for your needs), you could just draw a line in the direction of the satellite and then use the Elevation Service.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/elevation-paths

Comment: I need only ArcMap solution...